# Fastest X++ code to populate temp table

Tags: axapta, temp-tables, x++

I need to loop on InventTrans to cumulate itemId quantities for some dates and populate a temp table with the results in a form using this temp table as datasource. I used a class and the process is quite long (about 5-10 seconds) for an itemId.

Which code is fastest?

1. using a class that does the process
2. methods on the temp table
3. process with a button clicked() on the caller form

How can I improve my code?

Comment: Please show your code. The problem may be in your code and not with your process. I have done similar things with much better results, but I can not help without knowing what it is you are doing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you do not show your code, improving on it will be purely speculative.

I would rule out number 3 entirely; putting business logic in clicked methods is not an option.

Things to consider:

- Client/server: Prefer putting the logic and data access on the server side, use the `server` keyword on the table method or class static method (or use class property). Avoid call back to client for parameters etc.
- Data access: Consider index usage, use field list in select etc.
- Transactions: Use ttsbegin/ttscommit outside main loop, it speeds disc access even for temp tables.
- TempDB tables: In AX 2012 consider using TempDB tables populated with `insert_recordset`.
- Avoid using temp tables, if possible: In your case the `InventSum` table may have the data ready for you. Use the `sum` keyword in the select, combined with join on the `InventDim` table. Consider making a view to do the hard work. This will make the SQL server do the calculation, which typically results in a two-digit factor increase in performance.

Long queries? Enable SQL logging of long queries in your user settings.

What is the time spent on? Use the code profiler.

Comment: "In your case the InventSum table may already have the data for you."  A fantastic observation.